# CommandRegistrationError kil is already exisiting with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started coding in discord.py when I try:

```
@bot.command()
async def kil(ctx, username: discord.User): 
await ctx.send(username,"was killed")

bot.add_command(kil)
```

but when I run it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 63, in 
> bot.add_command(kil)
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1149, in add_command
> raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command kil is already an existing command or alias.

pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to you defining it as a command using the decorator `@bot.command()` and adding the command using `bot.add_command`. You are basically trying to make it a command twice. Use the decorator over the method as it is more standard and cleaner.

The answer below is incorrect as having the same command as a different bot would not make a difference.